# Appcelerator Arrowdb deleting photo does not work

Tags: appcelerator, arrowdb

I'm trying to delete a photo in Arrowdb using the REST API.

I'm sending in both "id" and "su_id" (of the user who uploaded it). And I am currently logged in as an admin with admin rights.

I keep getting the following response:

```
 { ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["status"]=> string(4) "fail" ["code"]=>    int(400) ["message"]=> string(27) "Failed to authenticate user" }
```

Anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: The message seems to say the admin credentials are not correct. If you are sure they are then please contact support@appcelerator.com

Comment: My fault. Was using PHP and curl. But forgot to add the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE which meant the session did not stay over the curl calls. When i added those it works, so working as it should in arrowdb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using curl and PHP, forgot to add the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to the curl call, which meant the session did not get through and no user was logged in at arrowdb. With those parameters added it worked correctly.